# How do i open a fragment after clicking a Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have created a GridView for a set of theaters in my application. My Theater class extends Fragment and it gets data from a JSON. What i want is to open another fragment called movie details upon clicking a item in gridview. 
for example if i click a theater from my gridview ,then moviedetails class should open and show it's layout. How can i achieve this?

My theater class

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.content.Intent;

    import android.widget.AdapterView;


    import com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.LazyAdapter;
    import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
    import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.CommonVariable;
    import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.JSONServices;
    import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

    public class TheaterFragment extends Fragment {

        private GridView gridView;

        private ArrayList<BaseElement> filmTheater;
        private LazyAdapter adapter;
        private Activity activity;
        private CommonVariable commonVariable;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theater_fragment, container,
                    false);

            activity = this.getActivity();

            commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

            gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);






                    new BackGround().execute();

            return view;
        }



        public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                filmTheater = JSONServices.getTheater();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            /* check again */
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                commonVariable.setTheater(filmTheater);

                adapter = new LazyAdapter(filmTheater, activity,
                        Element.THEATER_LIST.getType());

                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

        }

        }
```

movie details class (this is the class i should go upon clicking an item from the gridview)

```
 package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class MovieDetailFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shortfilm, container,
                    false);


            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it the best way to make theater layout by using grid view? I need suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new MovieDetailFragment(); 
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
```

Thanks.

Comment: put this code into OnItemClick of gridview. to open MovieDetailFragment.

Comment: at the moment i do not have a OnItemClick for gridview.can you help me with that? because i'm a super beginner at android

Comment: For gridview example refer this link : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: can you tell me how to add multiple fragments by clicking on different items on gridview

Answer (score 1):

You can use FragmentTransaction inside your click event:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
Fragment profileFragment = new MovieDetailFragment();//the fragment you want to show
profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Note:

Your fragment is missing an empty constructor.

Comment: i get errors at   getSupportFragmentManager()    ,   bundle     and when i replaced my layout in content_frame